# Difference between "бренчать" and "тренькать"

Tags: значения, музыка

can anyone explain to me the difference between these words, and maybe наматывать as well?

I was doing guitar-vocab, and my usual resources seem to be drawing a blank.

Answer (score 11):

Both mean making repetitive noise.

**Бренча́ть** is loud and annoying:

- Пиани́но сла́вно бренча́ло всё одну́ и ту же мело́дию.
- Звени́т гита́ра, бренчи́т бу́бен, у́хает бараба́н.
- Что́-то бормоча́, он бренча́л ключа́ми, ища́ тот, кото́рый ну́жен.
- Движо́к тря́сся, бренча́ кры́шкой капо́та.
- Э́то тебе́ не на балала́йке бренча́ть!

**Тре́нькать** is softer and more intermittent:

- Буфе́тчица погромы́хивала посу́дой, е́ле слы́шно тре́нькала кака́я-то му́зыка.
- На пери́лах терра́сы то́нко и остро́ тре́нькала кака́я-то пти́чка.
- В прохо́де сиде́л и бестолко́во тре́нькал на гита́ре пья́ный солда́тик.

Notice three distinct patterns:

- Бренча́ть на (prepositional) - Similar to **игра́ть на** (гита́ре, балала́йке).
- Бренча́ть (instrumental) - Make a noise with something (ключа́ми, кры́шкой).
- X бренчи́т. - X is making noise on its own.

When used with **на**, both refer to ineptly playing *on* a musical instrument.

You can find more examples on http://ruscorpora.ru.

Comment: This is hugely helpful, thanks. Id upvote it again if I could.